# handshake.getPeerCertificates() null pointers on a two way handshake

Tags: java, sockets, ssl, ssl-certificate

After my handshake is complete I call `getPeerCertificates()` on handshake (`socket.getHandshakeSession()`) I am using `setNeedClientAuth(true)` on the server socket so I know it must be getting the clients cert.

What could be going wrong? `SSLPeerUnverifiedException` is not thrown

```
ssf = (SSLServerSocketFactory)SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault();  
serverSocket = (SSLServerSocket)ssf.createServerSocket(PORT);  
serverSocket.setNeedClientAuth(true);
//added to after accept list and picked up by a worker thread.
SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) serverSocket.accept();

//worker thread.
SSLSession handshake = socket.getHandshakeSession();
Certificate[] certificates = handshake.getPeerCertificates(); // NULL
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call `socket.getHandshakeSession()`, you haven't started the handshake yet, and you certainly haven't reached the point where the client certificate is exchanged. Although calling `getSession()` is one way to start the handshake (see introduction of the [`SSLSocket`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocket.html) documentation, no such thing happens with `getHandshakeSession()` (as the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocket.html#getHandshakeSession%28%29) says: "*Unlike getSession(), this method does not initiate the initial handshake and does not block until handshaking is complete.*").

In most cases, you'll want to get the client certificate once the handshake has completed anyway. Calling `socket.getSession()` instead of `socket.getHandshakeSession()` (an addition in Java 7) is likely to solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks. I wrongly assumed that `accept()` would start the handshake.